# Re-arranging List in R

Tags: r

I have a list with of two securities, both of which have a "date" and "price". Instead of showing the output one below the other I am trying to move the prices of security 2 (XETUSD) next to the prices of security 1 (XBT) to have 1 date column and the following two to be the prices of the two securities

Extracted output DPUT

```
list(`XBTUSD BGN Curncy` = structure(list(date = structure(c(18107, 
18108, 18109, 18110), class = "Date"), PX_LAST = c(9541.65, 10026.61, 
10411.97, 10399.38)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
4L)), `XETUSD BGN Curncy` = structure(list(date = structure(c(18107, 
18108, 18109, 18110), class = "Date"), PX_LAST = c(209.24, 215.38, 
217.64, 215.647)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L
)))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to add your code, so we can see what your list looks like and what you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dcast(rbindlist(your_list, idcol = 'idx'), date ~ idx, value.var = 'PX_LAST')
```

Output:

```
         date XBTUSD BGN Curncy XETUSD BGN Curncy
1: 2019-07-30           9541.65           209.240
2: 2019-07-31          10026.61           215.380
3: 2019-08-01          10411.97           217.640
4: 2019-08-02          10399.38           215.647
```

Answer (score 1):

We could bind the rows together in `list_df` and `spread` it to wide format

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(list_df, .id = "security") %>%
   tidyr::spread(security, PX_LAST)


#       date  XBTUSD BGN Curncy XETUSD BGN Curncy
#1 2019-07-30           9541.65           209.240
#2 2019-07-31          10026.61           215.380
#3 2019-08-01          10411.97           217.640
#4 2019-08-02          10399.38           215.647
```

In base R, we can use `Reduce` with `merge`

```
out <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "date"), list_df)
names(out)[-1] <- names(list_df)
```